# Word redefinition in Forth

Tags: forth

In Forth, in case of re-definition of word, what is the expected behavior of another word that uses the re-defined one?
For e.g. if `x` calls `y`:

```
: Y ." Old Y " CR ;
: X 10 0 DO Y LOOP ;
\ ... 
: Y ." New Y " ;
```

then after the re-definition of `Y`, what should be the output of `X`, `Old Y` or `New Y` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer: `X` will output `Old Y`, see also your example in [online test](https://repl.it/FB9P/1/). At the time when `Y` is defined in the second time, the `X` is already compiled.

In Forth, redefinition is just shadowing: it is the case when the name of a new definition shadows some another name in the same word list, and the shadowed definition becomes inaccessible (unfindable) by this name.

Also Forth uses incremental compilation and static [name resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)) (that is performed in compile time). As the result, the new definitions don't affect any previous definitions (and already compiled code).

Comment: FWIW, if some kind of "polymorphic" behaviour is desired, `DEFER` and `IS` can be used, if your Forth supports them.

Comment: Yes. And in any case, the variables can be used to achieve the same result.