# Why are all words in Forth by default global?

Tags: forth

I am learning Forth. Why are all words in the language by default global?

Correct me please if I am naming keys of dictionary correctly -- words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are talking about [scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)), I think the reason is that the global scope is just the simplest approach that is available anywhere.

Yes, by default all standard and user-defined words have global scope. But for each word its scope begins at its **definition end** only (so on [redefinition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487349/word-redefinition-in-forth), the previous word can be used in the definition of the new word with the same name). And the scope of local variables is limited by the definition body where these variables are declared.

Forth also provides more advanced techniques to control words visibility.

The words are grouped into word lists (a kind of [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_(programming)#In_programming_languages)). And any part of a program can be excluded from the scope of a word list (i.e. the words from this word list). For that this word list should be excluded from the [search order](https://forth-standard.org/standard/search) at the start of this part of the program (and reverted at the end).
Likewise, any part of a program can be included into the scope of a word list by including this word list into the search order (and reverting at the end). Of course, we have the effect of [name masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)#Name_masking) in this case.

Also many Forth systems provide an API that allows to use the names that are partially qualified by word lists.
For example: `module1::submodule2::word3`, where `module1` is a word that is available by the search order, and that returns a word list identifier *wid1*. `submodule2` is a word that is defined in the word list *wid1*, and that returns a word list identifier *wid2*, `word3` is a word that is defined in the word list *wid2*.
(See `RESOLVE-PQNAME` word in [my implementation](https://github.com/ruv/forth-design-exp/blob/master/lexeme-translator/resolver.stdlib.fth) as a reference).

To have a shorter access to some module, you can define your synonym, e.g. `module1::submodule2 constant m` and use prefix `m::` to access the words from this sub-module as `m::word3`.

Answer (score 2):

On my Forth system, words by default are created in the *FORTH* vocabulary. Check your Forth's documentation for *VOCABULARY* and *WORDLIST*. I can create any vocabularies I need and make them the default instead. Below is a simple manipulation to create two words with the same name in two vocabularies and how to access them.

```
\ Create two vocabularies ( in the FORTH vocabulary )
VOCABULARY ENGLISH
VOCABULARY FRENCH

ORDER   \ Show the search order and current vocabulary
\ FORTH  EXTERNALS  ROOT
\ Current: FORTH

ALSO ENGLISH
ORDER
\ ENGLISH  FORTH  EXTERNALS  ROOT  \ ENGLISH added to the search order
\ Current: FORTH                   \ New words created in FORTH

DEFINITIONS  ok      \ Change 'Current' to the top of the search order.
ORDER
\ ENGLISH  FORTH  EXTERNALS  ROOT
\ Current: ENGLISH                 \ New words created in ENGLISH

: trans  \ n -- ;
  1- 6 * s" One   Two   Three Four  " DROP + 6 TYPE ;

PREVIOUS  \ Remove the top vocabulary from the search order
ORDER
\ FORTH  EXTERNALS  ROOT  \ ENGLISH dropped from the search order.
\ Current: ENGLISH        \ but still where new words will be created.

ALSO FRENCH DEFINITIONS
ORDER
\ FRENCH  FORTH  EXTERNALS  ROOT
\ Current: FRENCH                 \ New words created in FRENCH

: trans  \ n -- ;
  1- 6 * s" Un    Deux  Trois Quatre" DROP + 6 TYPE ;

PREVIOUS DEFINITIONS

ALSO ENGLISH
1 trans 2 trans 3 trans 4 trans
\ One   Two   Three Four   ok

PREVIOUS ALSO FRENCH
1 trans 2 trans 3 trans 4 trans
\ Un    Deux  Trois Quatre ok
```

For example, the assembler will be in another VOCABULARY which is switched on once the CODE defining word is executed. After that, any words are first searched in the *ASSEMBLER* vocabulary.

Some Forth implementations allow *MODULES*. I've never used them, but check the documentation for your system.